# Closed form formula for $2^{2^1}+2^{2^2}+...+2^{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So, the series's sum is of below form:

$2^{2^1}+2^{2^2}+...+2^{2^n}$

This series is an intermediate work of an bigger problem {So I am concerned with whether $2^{2^n}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(2^{2^i})}{2}$ is anywhere close to $2^{2^{n-1}}$}. With limited knowledge of series, I am stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: Might I ask the statement of the *bigger problem* ? :-)

Comment: I don't think that there is any closed form for the summation. What you could notice is that the last term is extremely predominent. For $n=5$, the last term is $4294967296$ while the summation is $4295033108$; for $n=6$, the last term is $18446744073709551616$ while the summation is $18446744078004584724$. So, if $n$ is large, the summation is the last term with a very marginal error.

Comment: @sciona So I am concerned with whether $2^{2^n}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(2^{2^i})}{2}$ is anywhere close to $2^{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: Is this related to [Fermat number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  I think that is a good answer.  It is clearly applicable to the last specific question, saying the expression is quite close to $2^{2^n}$, which is correct.  The fundamental idea is that power towers only depend on the top exponent.

Comment: Pushing my calculation for $n=10$, the ratio between the summation and the last term is $1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \approx 7.46 \times 10^{-155}$

Comment: @Lucian No, it's not related to modular arithmetic

Comment: It is not close to $2^{2^{n-1}}$ but rather $2^{2^{n}-1}$

Comment: @Winther: and even closer to $2^{2^n}$

Comment: @RossMillikan No. My comment was related to the sum $2^{2^n} - \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{2^i}}{2}$ OP asks: "Is this close to $2^{2^{n-1}}$"

Comment: @Winther:  you are right because the largest term in the sum is half $2^{2^n}$, so yours is much closer than mine.

Comment: Your sum is A060803(n)-2, related to the sequence https://oeis.org/A060803 . This doesn't help much but at least shows that you aren't missing any obvious closed form.  See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2396259/24908 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple thing is to look at the ratio of the two largest terms.  $$\frac {2^{2^n}}{2^{2^{(n-1)}}}=2^{2^n-2^{(n-1)}}=2^{2^{(n-1)}}$$ which grows *rapidly* with $n$.  The smaller terms are really negligible and the sum is very close to $2^{2^n}$.  Note that you should be adding to, not subtracting from, the largest term.  My argument says you don't have to bother.