# Closed form for $S_n = \sum_{i = 0}^n r^{n^i} = r + r^n + r^{n^2} + r^{n^3} + \cdots + r^{n^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

> Find a closed form equation for the sum $$S_n = \sum_{i = 0}^n r^{n^i} = r + r^n + r^{n^2} + r^{n^3} + \cdots + r^{n^n}$$

I don't really think this is solvable. I tried with multiplying both side by something, and writing an terms of $S_n$ but it didn't help. Is it actually solvable?

Comment: The limit as $n\to\infty$ is a [Lacunary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function), which have no such closed form. If there were a closed form in terms of $n$, then there'd probably be a closed form for the limit.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I didn't know about Lacunary Functions. But all the functions in the wiki page has sum to the infinity .. My one in finite :| (lol)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Actually, given the repetition of $n$ in the sum makes this not a series, and thus not related to Lacunary. Indeed, $S_n\to r$ for $|r|<1$.

Comment: Lacunary would be the limit of $\sum_{i=0}^{n} r^{q^i}$ for fixed $q$. @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: Ah, okay @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Well still, I highly doubt of any closed form.

Comment: Me too. @SimplyBeautifulArt :)

Comment: Why would you even imagine it has a closed form?

Comment: @GEdgar Why would you discourage curiosity?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072907/24908 for the case when r = n = 2.